# What JARs are needed for Espresso testing?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am starting to use Espresso for testing in an android app and I am having a problem setting up the JARs and was wondering if anyone could help me with the set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download JARs here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/#git%2Fbin%2Fespresso2.0

You probably want `espresso-core-2.0.jar`. You might also want to download the sources jar so that you can easily see what espresso methods are doing, but it's not required. `espresso-contrib-2.0.jar` has some extra utilities which you may or may not find useful.

That said, I would consider adopting gradle and adding the dependencies in Andy's answer. Manually managing JARs tends to get burdensome, especially if you have collaborators in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> What JARs are needed for Espresso testing?

None.
(well, in the sense that you are no longer required manually to deal with jar files)

I am assuming you are using a gradle based project. And if so, you have to add just the below dependencies to your module, in order to set up Espresso.

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
```

As a prerequisite, make sure you have downloaded `Android Support Repository`, from: `SDK Manager -> Extras -> Android Support Repository.`

You can find more info about Espresso setup, in this page: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question but I am not using Gradle or any other build tool.